# Can i consume WCF service inside windows mobile 6 project?

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-mobile-6

Can i consume WCF service inside windows mobile 6 project??
I spend many days to solve my problem of adding web reference of WCF to smartdevice project
but the smae error appears.

> There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/mex'.
>   Unable to connect to the remote server
>   No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8731
>   There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:8731/Desi

**So i ask is it possible to consume WCF from windows mobile 6 project??**

I create WCF and windows mobile projects in visual studio 2008 and when i "add web reference" to the mobile project to add the WCF and put the URL i get this error
"There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/mex'.
Unable to connect to the remote server
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8731
There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:8731/Desi"
however i change the "localhost" to my computer IP address the same error appeared.
How can i write the URL that will be put in the client application.

Comment: Most probably, your service is not at your mobile device :) see http://`localhost`:8731

Comment: @L.B If I'm reading the question right, the error occurs when he tries to add the service reference into the project in VS, not at runtime.

Comment: @Inerdial, OK. the service, at least, is not at where he/she develops the client side code(or port number is different). Or both projects are in the same solution and client side code is marked as `startup project`, so server is not running while trying to add the web reference

Comment: @Inerdial you are right.

Comment: @L.B i run it on my laptop is this the problem??

Comment: @Yasmeen, No, the problem can be **a)** your service is not running while you are trying to add the web reference. **b)** your service is not at the host you develop your client side code(`localhost`) **c)** the port of your service is different than 8731

Answer (score 1):

The important part of the error is "Unable to connect"

This means that the add service reference has tried to make a call to the service, but the call failed.

The most likely reasons for this are:

1. The service is not running
2. The metadata exchange (mex endpoint) is not enabled

Comment: The WCF doesn't hosted on the IIS.Is this the problem??or not??

Comment: @Yasmeen, No it is not a problem. But don't forget it to run before you try to add web reference

Comment: Till now i can't make "add web reference".So its the problem.this right or not??

Comment: The "add web reference" is not the cause of the problem. The problem is that the service is not replying with a description of the service.

Comment: @Yasmeen did you make sure to start your WCF service from Visual Studio before trying to add a reference to it as Shiraz points out, it looks like the service might not be running?

Comment: The WCF and The mobile project in the same solution.But when i click the links "Web services in this solution 
" the appeared message says thats "None - No Web services were found in the current solution."

Comment: It looks like there are some problems with the project that contains the wcf services. Try creating a new WCF project with a new service.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to get the Mex, but the service isn't running on the dev machine:

Try going to this url in your browser

http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/mex

you'll probably get the same error (machine actively refused it)

Make sure the service is started.

Comment: When i try it on the browser i got white page there is no any errors.
have i host the WCF on the IIS first then consume it on the mobile project this what you means by "Make sure the service is started."

Comment: So is the URL you're configuring for the service reference on the mobile device also a localhost URL? Or are you changing the host name to be the host that's also running the service? And is that host serving external clients, i.e. can you access it from other machines to make sure it's not being firewalled off?